# TranslateApiException in Microsoft Translator in java

Tags: java, localization, language-translation, microsoft-translator

I'm currently trying to connect to Microsoft Translator via `microsoft-translator-java-api` provided [here](http://code.google.com/p/microsoft-translator-java-api/). I've followed the step described [here](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis) and after following the simple code [here](http://code.google.com/p/microsoft-translator-java-api/source/browse/trunk/microsoft-translator-java-examples/src/main/java/com/memetix/mst/examples/TranslateExample.java), I managed to send some sentence to be translated.

But the problem is, the translation only work for the **1st time**. When the second sentence is send to the api, `TranslateApiException` always generated as translation result and I have to wait for about 10 minutes before new sentence can be sent.

Can anyone help?
thanks before

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot this:

1. Make sure you have a subscription to translator. Sign in here: https://datamarket.azure.com/account/datasets

-- Does it show that you have a translator subscription, and that it is active? If not, sign up for one (you can use the free 2 million character one)

1. Make sure you have registered your app on Azure. Do that here:
   https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications

-- And use the Client ID and Client Secret for that registered app.